# Deviseで保存されたUserの暗号化パスワードと入力パスワードの同値確認方法は？

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, rubygems

DeviseでUser管理をしています。保存されたパスワードはencrypted_passwordとして暗号化されて保存されています。
Deviseのログイン画面とは別にDeviseを使わないログイン画面を作る必要が出てきました。

パラメータから受け取ったparams[:password]と既にDeviseのsign_upから登録済のUserのencrypted_passwordが同値であるか（ログインが許可できるか？）はどう判断すればいいのでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`valid_password?`メソッドを使ってください。
以下は実行例です。

```
user = User.find_by_email(params[:email])
user.valid_password?(params[:password])
```

参考: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4320921/how-verify-user-password-in-devise

Comment: できました！ありがとうございます！Junichi Itoさんのblogも時々参考にしております。

Comment: それは良かったです！ブログもよんでくださってどうもありがとうございます。
あと、僕の回答で問題がないようであればベストアンサーを選んでもらうとすでに解決済みの質問としてマークされるので他の利用者にとってもわかりやすくなります。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

Devise の設定によって色々と方法が異なりますが、デフォルトの設定であると仮定すると、以下のようなコードで同値であるかどうか判定できます。クラス名や文字列の部分は、適切なものに変えてください。

test.rb

```
require "rubygems"
require "active_model"

class User
  include ActiveModel::SecurePassword
  has_secure_password
  attr_accessor :password_digest
end

a = User.new
a.password_digest = "User#encrypted_password の値を入れてください"

if a.authenticate "入力されたパスワードを入れてください"
  puts "success"
else
  puts "fail"
end
```

実行結果

```
$ ruby test.rb
success
```